# Storing third value of given column in new column for each group in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
USER.ID ISO_DATE
1   3   2014-05-02
2   3   2014-05-05
3   3   2014-05-06
4   3   2014-05-20
5   3   2014-05-21
6   3   2014-05-24
7   3   2014-06-09
8   3   2014-06-14
9   3   2014-06-18
10  3   2014-06-26
11  3   2014-07-11
12  3   2014-07-21
13  3   2014-07-22
14  3   2014-07-25
15  3   2014-07-27
16  3   2014-08-03
17  3   2014-08-07
18  3   2014-08-12
19  3   2014-08-13
20  3   2014-08-16
21  3   2014-08-17
22  3   2014-08-20
23  3   2014-08-22
24  3   2014-08-31
25  3   2014-10-22
26  3   2014-11-19
27  3   2014-11-20
28  3   2014-11-23
29  3   2014-11-25
30  3   2014-12-06
31  3   2014-12-09
32  3   2014-12-10
33  3   2014-12-12
34  3   2014-12-14
35  3   2014-12-14
36  3   2014-12-14
37  3   2014-12-15
38  3   2014-12-16
39  3   2014-12-17
40  3   2014-12-18
41  3   2014-12-20
42  3   2015-01-08
43  3   2015-01-09
44  3   2015-01-11
45  3   2015-01-12
46  3   2015-01-14
47  3   2015-01-15
48  3   2015-01-18
49  3   2015-01-18
50  3   2015-01-19
51  3   2015-01-21
52  3   2015-01-22
53  3   2015-01-22
54  3   2015-01-23
55  3   2015-01-26
56  3   2015-01-27
57  3   2015-01-28
58  3   2015-01-29
59  3   2015-01-30
60  3   2015-01-30
61  3   2015-02-01
62  3   2015-02-02
63  3   2015-02-03
64  3   2015-02-04
65  3   2015-02-08
66  3   2015-02-09
67  3   2015-02-10
68  3   2015-02-13
69  3   2015-02-15
70  3   2015-02-16
71  3   2015-02-19
72  3   2015-02-20
73  3   2015-02-21
74  3   2015-02-23
75  3   2015-02-26
76  3   2015-02-28
77  3   2015-03-01
78  3   2015-03-11
79  3   2015-03-18
80  3   2015-03-22
81  3   2015-03-28
82  3   2015-04-03
83  3   2015-04-07
84  3   2015-04-08
85  3   2015-04-08
86  3   2015-04-15
87  3   2015-04-19
88  3   2015-04-21
89  3   2015-04-22
90  3   2015-04-24
91  3   2015-04-28
92  3   2015-05-03
93  3   2015-05-03
94  3   2015-05-04
95  3   2015-05-06
96  3   2015-05-08
97  3   2015-05-15
98  3   2015-05-16
99  3   2015-05-16
100 3   2015-05-19
101 3   2015-05-21
102 3   2015-05-21
103 3   2015-05-22
104 5   2015-02-05
105 7   2015-01-02
106 7   2015-01-03
107 7   2015-01-25
108 7   2015-02-21
109 7   2015-02-28
110 7   2015-03-02
111 7   2015-03-02
112 7   2015-03-07
113 7   2015-03-14
114 7   2015-05-01
115 9   2014-03-12
116 9   2014-03-12
117 9   2014-03-19
118 9   2014-04-10
119 9   2014-04-10
120 9   2014-04-10
121 9   2014-04-11
122 9   2014-05-30
123 9   2014-05-30
124 9   2014-06-06
125 9   2014-06-07
126 9   2014-06-14
127 9   2014-10-17
128 9   2014-10-17
129 9   2014-10-17
130 9   2014-10-17
131 9   2014-10-17
132 9   2014-10-17
133 9   2014-10-17
134 9   2014-10-19
135 9   2014-10-20
136 9   2014-10-20
137 9   2014-12-20
138 13  2014-07-08
139 13  2014-07-08
140 13  2014-07-08
141 13  2014-07-11
142 13  2014-07-11
143 13  2014-07-18
144 13  2014-07-19
145 13  2014-07-23
146 13  2014-07-23
147 13  2014-07-27
148 13  2014-07-29
149 13  2014-07-31
150 13  2014-08-02
151 13  2014-08-03
152 13  2014-08-06
153 13  2014-08-14
154 13  2014-08-14
155 13  2014-08-18
156 13  2014-08-19
157 13  2014-08-26
158 13  2014-08-30
159 13  2014-09-02
160 13  2014-09-10
161 13  2014-09-12
162 13  2014-09-13
163 13  2014-09-18
164 13  2014-09-20
165 13  2014-09-21
166 13  2014-09-24
167 13  2014-09-28
168 13  2014-09-30
169 13  2014-10-04
170 13  2014-10-09
171 13  2014-10-15
172 13  2014-10-20
173 13  2014-10-20
174 13  2014-10-20
175 13  2014-10-20
176 13  2014-10-25
177 13  2014-10-26
178 13  2014-10-29
179 13  2014-11-10
180 13  2014-11-28
181 13  2014-11-28
182 13  2014-11-28
183 13  2014-11-28
184 13  2014-11-29
185 13  2014-12-03
186 13  2014-12-05
187 13  2014-12-05
188 13  2014-12-10
189 13  2015-01-03
190 13  2015-03-08
191 13  2015-03-22
192 13  2015-04-06
193 13  2015-04-16
194 13  2015-04-21
195 13  2015-04-22
196 13  2015-04-26
197 13  2015-05-05
198 13  2015-05-07
199 13  2015-05-15
200 13  2015-05-21
201 16  2014-03-11
202 16  2014-03-13
203 16  2014-03-15
204 16  2014-04-12
205 16  2014-04-14
206 16  2014-04-23
207 16  2014-05-26
208 16  2014-05-30
209 16  2014-05-31
210 16  2014-06-10
211 16  2014-06-26
212 16  2014-08-18
213 16  2014-08-21
214 16  2014-08-24
215 16  2014-08-29
216 16  2014-09-01
217 16  2014-09-07
218 16  2014-09-15
219 16  2014-09-17
220 16  2014-09-24
221 16  2014-09-29
222 16  2014-10-06
223 16  2014-10-07
224 16  2014-10-08
225 16  2014-10-20
226 16  2014-10-20
227 16  2014-10-20
228 16  2014-11-12
229 16  2014-11-12
```

I want to create a two new columns that would store 3rd and 6th value of ISO_DATE for each USER.ID separately.

I tried this:

```
users <- users %>%
arrange(USER.ID) %>%
group_by(USER.ID) %>%
mutate(third_date = head(ISO_DATE, 3)) %>%
mutate(fifth_date = head(ISO_DATE, 6))
```

but it is not helping. Is there a way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the 'ISO_DATE' column to 'Date' class (if it is not), `group_by` 'USER.ID', `arrange` the 'ISO_DATE' and create new columns with 3rd and 6th observation of 'ISO_DATE'

```
library(dplyr)
users1 <- users %>%
            mutate(ISO_DATE = as.Date(ISO_DATE)) %>% 
            group_by(USER.ID) %>% 
            arrange(ISO_DATE) %>% 
            mutate(third_date = ISO_DATE[3L], sixth_date=ISO_DATE[6L])
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(users)[, ISO_DATE:= as.Date(ISO_DATE)
           ][order(ISO_DATE), 
               c('third_date', 'sixth_date') := list(ISO_DATE[3L], ISO_DATE[6L]) ,
            by= USER.ID]
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Just wanted to know what does [3L] do ?

Comment: @DheerajSingh It is just indexing as a integer value instead of numeric.  Suppose I use `[3]` it will be numeric.  Indexing by integer will be a bit faster.  i.e. `str(3)#num 3` and `str(3L)#
 int 3`